# How do I select a static string in a SQL query and ensure its type is VARCHAR2?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query that is executed on a remote database:

```
select /*+ DRIVING_SITE(rd) */ 'test' as tst, rd.id from mytable@remotedb rd
```

When I execute this query I get:

```
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

Every column in `mytable@remotedb` is either `INTEGER` or `VARCHAR2`.

If I remove `'test' as tst` there is no problem, so it appears the static string `'test'` is somehow being formatted as a `CLOB` rather than the `VARCHAR2` I assumed it would.

Do I need to cast this to a `VARCHAR2`?  This seems odd... is there a better way to create static return strings in a query that ensures they will be `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: What are the versions of each of the Oracle instances?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: 10.2.0.4.0 / 64bit for both databases.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The charsets differ, however: US7ASCII locally and WE8ISO8859P1 on the remote database.

Comment: The issue is beyond me, but googling I saw the error occur do to issues with syntax relating to mismatched versions.

Comment: One of those Google hits: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=317043 - perhaps try some of the ideas there - e.g. use a synonym on the table, or a view; what about putting TO_CHAR() around the string?

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp:  I gave to_char a try but no luck.  I ran across this blog entry: http://grouchgeek.blogspot.com/2008/02/ora-22992-oracle-hell.html and it seems to indicate that this is an Oracle bug.  The recommendation is to use old Oracle join syntax rather than the new ANSI syntax (which I'm doing in my actual query).  Surprisingly, none of the tables I'm touching have LOBs in them.  Unfortunately I am using the new ANSI syntax so that I can do a full outer join, so I guess I have to use an inefficient inline view to get what I want.

Comment: What happens if you remove the DRIVING_SITE hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the error has nothing to do with LOBs, and I suspect you're right that this is an Oracle bug. Try the workaround (i.e. replace the ANSI syntax with the older Oracle syntax) and if it works, that's probably what you'll have to put up with until you upgrade the database.

Comment: Oracle syntax fixed it, but it's not a very pretty sight.  Since my data is so closely tied to that in the remote database I've decided to migrate everything there.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but I notice that the query selects "mt.id" from the remote table, but the alias of the remote table is "rd".

Try the following:

```
select /*+ DRIVING_SITE(rd) */ 'test' as tst, rd.id from mytable@remotedb rd
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @RenderIn - kinda thought so, but figured it was worth mentioning.  FWIW, I ran a more-or-less equivalent test and found that under 11G no problems were reported.